# NoDisplay Activity sometimes shows as empty Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I have an Activity which is declared in the Manifest as following:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
```

Where Theme.Transparent is:

```
 <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

In this Activity I am showing dialogs and the dialogs then (in postExecute of my AsyncTask) open up another activity.
The dialog opens directly when the Activity has been started.

Now sometimes it just shows an Empty Activity without loading the dialog (I guess I did something wrong with my Activity lifecycle?!)
I have set a noHistory Flag in the Manifest so that if in the Activity which is started the back button is clicked you don't get to an empty Activity but exit the App completely...

Here is the structure of my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// setting up and showing dialog etc...
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    finish();
}

}
```

Thanks alot for your help...

Comment: try with noHistory = "false";

Comment: put your dialog display logic in onresume instead of oncreate

Comment: noHistory = "false"; didnt fix the problem.
@AndroidCoader What would that change exactly?

Comment: onCreate call only once when the activity created & onResume will call when ever your activity get resumed or started.

Comment: This did not fix it:( Or do I need to have noHistory set to true for it to work?